# Do I Need To Create Mock Classes For Every Class?

Tags: test-design, unit-tests

Let's say I have a system composed of three classes: A,B,C that share certain dependencies.

To test A independently, I would need to create mock objects for B and C
To test B independently, I would need to create mock objects for A and C etc...

So if I want to write tests for A, B, and C, I would need to create mock classes for each one of them.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your example to mean A, B, and C are all interdependent, i.e. there are six edges in the dependency graph.  Before considering how to unit test such a design, you might ask yourself whether you really need that many dependencies.   It's a nice idea for a society but not for a code base.  A large number of interdependencies is a forbearer of brittle, hard-to-maintain code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, but this is often overkill. Ideally your application should have been programmed to interfaces and you should be able to **choose** to mock out the interfaces that allow you to test components independently.

Comment: +1 Using interfaces decouples the application making it robust enough for future changes. It also follows the "Law of Demeter" design principle eliminating dependencies

Answer (score 0):

One would want to mock dependencies.  If A depended (ie used) B and C, one might need to mock B and C depending upon whether or not that particular test uses them.

The creation of a mock is also not a one-time thing.  Mocks are used to test expectations and force certain behavior (eg function throwing an exception in order to test exception handling).